# Consider the subspace W spanned by $t^2+t+2, t^2+2t+5, 5t^2+3t+4, and \thinspace 2t^2+2t+4$ Then, dimension of W is,

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ b the vector space of all real polynomials.  Consider the subspace W spanned by 
$t^2+t+2,   t^2+2t+5,  5t^2+3t+4,  and \thinspace 2t^2+2t+4$ Then, dimension of W is,

I don't know how to proceed it can anyone please help me

Thank you

Comment: You proceed (begin) with the _definitions_. What is your definition of "dimension", for instance? That will tell you _exactly_ what you're actually asked to look for. What is the definition of "span"? That will tell you what you are actually working with here. Then you can start looking for theorems that might help you, like something talking about the dimension of a span.

Comment: A question that may help is what is a basis (find a set of polynomials whose linear combinations construct all real polynomials) of the vector space of real polynomials? One hint is the basis will be infinite